# Yii2 FileHelper::findFiles() - error with non-ASCII characters

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, internationalization, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm developing an app from the yii2-advanced-app.

In a controller (DocumentController) I read out files in a directory with the **FileHelper::findFiles()**.

It's working, but if my filename contains non-ASCII characters (like the German umlauts, äöü) I only get a question mark in the returning file-path.

How do I solve this? I can't find a suitable answer.

As the web server I'm using IIS 7 on a [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 Enterprise.

**DocumentController.php**

```
use yii\helpers\FileHelper;

$data = FileHelper::findFiles($folderPath,['except'=>['*.db']]);

var_dump($data);
```

**The result is:**

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(84) "C:\Websites\dev.point-s.de\space/space_attachments/10082\Aushang 201501 Gr�ndung.pdf" }
```

---

The output should be done with the following code, but I think the problem is the reading of the files.

```
Html::a($model['name'], ['document/download', 'file' => $model['name']])
```

Comment: `var_dump` not using any encoding. Set utf-8 `header`  before dumping.

Comment: Please explain what exactly not working.

Comment: I have files in directory which should be listed in a list (<ul><li>Html::a($filename, ['document/download', 'file' => $model['name']])<li></ul>).

When the filename contains special charaters such as german umlauts (äöü) I only see the question mark shown above

Comment: did you set encoding to `utf-8` for your page?

Comment: as this is the default option in yii my page source code shows the line `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/639589/utf-8-filename-are-ruined-when-uploading-through-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanks @ineersa for trying to help, I got the answer with help from my coworker.

The solution is to explicit convert the filename returned by findFiles() to UTF-8 with the PHP function **`utf8_encode()`**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php